# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, hibernate-spatial

I am trying to fetch GIS data using nativeSQLQuery, but I am facng below issue.

Stack Trace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject

      at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryValueExtractor.toJTS(PGGeometryValueExtractor.java:113)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.doExtract(AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.java:50)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:258)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:71)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:100)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:77)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:425)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:753)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at uk.gov.os.maps.dao.impl.GISDataProviderDAOImpl.getBoroughRegionGISDataJsonStringFromDatabase(GISDataProviderDAOImpl.java:104)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
      at uk.gov.os.maps.service.impl.GISDataProviderServiceImpl.getBoroughRegionGISData(GISDataProviderServiceImpl.java:30)[uk.gov.os:os_esb:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]

      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_102]

      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_102]
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_102]
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_102]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:171)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:68)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProducer.process(BeanProducer.java:38)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-620133 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
      at org.apache.camel.component.http.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:144)[org.apache.camel:camel-http:2.15.1.redhat-620133]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)[org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0]
      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.17.v20150415 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415].....
```

Here are dependencies which I have used : hibernate,hibernatee-spatial and postgis

org.hibernate
            hibernate-entitymanager
            4.3.5.Final

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

org.postgis
            postgis-jdbc
            1.5.2

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
        <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
                <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Persistent.xml

Has anyone already faced this one?